# What is the opposite query to Model.where(field: nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a model named GuestOrder:

```
class GuestOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: guest_orders
#
#  id             :integer         not null, primary key
#  notes          :string(255)
#  adults         :integer
#  children       :integer
#  created        :datetime
#  placed         :datetime
#  billed         :datetime
#  user_id        :integer
#  guest_table_id :integer
#  take_away_id   :integer
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
```

Retrieving `GuestOrders` where `billed` is `nil` works well:

```
GuestOrder.where(billed: nil)
```

But how can I retrieve `GuestOrders` where `billed` is `not nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this!

```
GuestOrder.where("billed is not null")
```

That will work! That uses regular SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    GuestOrder.where("billed IS NOT NULL")
```

use capital letter IS NOT NULL........

Comment: Thanks Kashif ali,Both of your answers working well. But MrDanA answered  before you. So i accepted his answer.

Comment: Just a follow up, it shouldn't matter if you use capitals or not unless perhaps your database was configured to want capitals for the SQL key words.